# Is there such a function $f(a,b)=k$ where each value of $k$ appears only once for all integer values of $a$ and $b$?

Tags: provability

Suppose we have $f(a,b)=k$ such that $k$ is an integer when $a$ and $b$ are integers. Is there such a function where each value of $k$ appears only once for all integer values of $a$ and $b$?

e.g the function $f(a,b)=4ab+3a+2b$ satisfies the qualities for a and b between $0$ and $2$ inclusive.

I can find functions for small ranges of $a$ and $b$, but I have yet to find one that satisfies the property for all integers. Any thoughts?

Comment: $f(a,b) = 2^a 3^b.$

Comment: @B.Goddard I didn't even think about exponential equations, I'm a fantastic moron

Comment: @B.Goddard: that doesn't work for *all* integers $a,b$, because $2^a3^b$ isn't an integer for negative $a,b$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic  It's not clear to me that the OP wanted an onto function.  If so, we also have to worry about all the other primes.

Comment: It's not about being onto: your function isn't a map $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$. The OP didn't say *positive* integers.

Comment: @B.Goddard I did say all integers

Comment: @mcchucklezz  But "only once" is not the same as "exactly once."  So I took it to mean "Once or nonce."

Comment: @B.Goddard: you are straight up misreading. The issue is not surjectivity; it's that your function *doesn't have the right domain and co-domain*, regardless of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a standard bijection, the Cantor pairing function, which takes $(a, b) \mapsto \frac{1}{2} (a+b)(a+b+1) + b$. This is a bijection $\mathbb{N}  \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.

To create a bijection $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, just take your favourite bijection $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$ (e.g. if $n$ is nonpositive, send it to $-2n$, otherwise to $2n-1$), and compose with that.

Comment: I'll have to do some reading on these before I accept the answer, but what I do understand makes sense in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I can't quite tell whether you're asking for an injection or a bijection $f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$. (An injection guarantees that each $k$ is output only once, if it is output at all; but it may not be output unless we in fact have a bijection.)

There are infinitely many such functions, but here's a fun and rather natural injection. It has a "computational" flavor: unlike mysterious rabbit-out-of-the-hat Cantor factorizations, it is the sort of thing a programmer or cryptographer might think of.

---

To get an injection, we need to be able to recover the inputs based only on the output. So why not directly *encode* the inputs into the output? Given integers $a$ and $b$, take their binary numerals; interpret them as ternary numerals instead; then concatenate them with an intervening digit of $\mathtt{2}$. Then let $f(a,b)$ be the integer corresponding to that concatenated numeral. What about negatives? If $a$ is negative, tack on a $\mathtt{2}$ at the left of its binary numeral before concatenating; if $b$ is negative, tack on a $\mathtt{2}$ to the right of its binary numeral before concatenating. This way the ternary numeral of the output will always have at most three $\mathtt{2}$'s: one in the middle to separate the binary numerals of the inputs, and possibly two more at the edges, depending on whether the inputs are negative.

For example, $f(8,11)=6754$ because $8$ is $\mathtt{1000}$ in binary, and $11$ is $\mathtt{1011}$ in binary, so their concatenation according to the above scheme is $\mathtt{100021011}$, which represents the integer $6754$ in ternary. Similarly, $f(-1,3)=211$ because $1$ is $\mathtt{1}$ in binary, and we append a $\mathtt{2}$ at the front to get $\mathtt{21}$ before concatenating; $3$ is $\mathtt{11}$ in binary; so their concatenation is $\mathtt{21211}$, which represents the integer $211$.

Comment: Cantor's not really a rabbit out of a hat: it's just walking through the plane in diagonals.

Comment: Yes, of course, but it's the idea of walking through in diagonals that's a non-rabbit out of a non-hat, not the bald assertion of the final formula. :) In any case, I told a white lie to emphasize there are very different ways to think about the problem.